# Java service using Jersey won't deploy to Jboss

Tags: java, jersey, reset, ws

I'm trying to build a Java service that other services could call. 
This service is not a WS, but is calling a RestfulWS.

I'm really just building a wrapper around this call.  This would find the correct data it needs, set up the JSON for the call.   Get a response and send it back up.

Was told to use Jersey for this. Trying to set up all the pom.xml to use Jersey.
Building code works fine, it is when the deploy to the server happens that things fail. 
I get the error --  "JBAS011232: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed. "

I don't have a web.xml, which I guess is used to skip some ResetEasy files.
I do have exclusions in pom.xml and jboss-deployment-structure.xml.

I still get the error when deploy happens.   Not really sure what else to check.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a problem with JAX-RS dependencies. JBoss already has its own implementation of JAX-RS and probably that’s causing the issue. Some solutions are already suggested here [Jboss error: Only one JAX-RS Application Class allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575408/jboss-error-only-one-jax-rs-application-class-allowed)